# Definition of osculating plane

Tags: differential-geometry

I couldn't understand the exact geometrical meaning of the osculating plane definition. Can any one help me with this? Thanks advance.

Osculating plane: Let $\gamma$ be a smooth curve and P and Q be two neighboring points on $\gamma$. The limiting position of the plane that contains the tangential line at P and passes through the point Q as Q $\to$ P is defined as the osculating plane at P.

In another definition, osculating plane is a plane spanned by the tangent and normal line. But, I couldn't understand how we can find normal line geometrical?

Comment: The first definition seems perfectly clear. What's your question about it? As for the "normal" in the second definition, look up TNB frame - the normal vector of a curve is (proportional to) the derivative of the tangent vector (naturally parametrized).

Comment: Is it mean that limiting of the planes spanned by the tangent line and the line joining P and Q?

Comment: Is it possible to visualise that derivative of tangent vector with our calculations?

Comment: Yes to your first comment. Not sure what you're asking in the second comment.

Comment: Without taking derivative by looking at the curve itself can  possible to see that line?

Answer (score 1):

https://youtu.be/dJ6q3ZV_kjE
https://youtu.be/nLJy0B6CNMs
Please see these videos, it may help you. The language is not English, but I hope you can understand it by the 3D presentation.
However in simple language we can tell that, an oscillating plane is the plane containing curve's principal normal and tangent.